# htaccess redirect url with parameter variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect traffic when user visit my site from a specific url.
* `CATEGORY_ID` will be alpha_numeric 

`//domain.net/news/cat/{CATEGORY_ID}`

should be redirected to

`//other.com/#/id/{CATEGORY_ID}`

my attempt [from this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/481128/htaccess-redirect-with-parameters)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/cat/(.+)$
RewriteRule .* //other.com/#/id/%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

gave a 404 error.

Any help please, thank you!

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/cat/(.+)$ http://exemple.com/\x2523/id/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: the `#` is coming out as `%23`, do you know how to keep the actual hash in the url?

Comment: Try with `\%23`

Comment: same result using `\%23`

Comment: And with `\x2523` ?

Comment: the url returns the literal value never returning back to hash

Comment: by re organizing htaccess it worked with the original hash, thank you